# Complex Analysis, surjections whose domains are proper subsets of C

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a surjective analytic map onto C with domain a proper subset of C?
My guess is that there are. If the mappings are conformal and bijective, then such a map does not exist. I am unable to get a map satisfying the hypothesis. Will someone help please??

Comment: take $z^2$ on any domain that includes $\Re z \ge 0$, for example, $\Re z > -1$

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear to me.